# Threading when sending emails

Tags: c#, multithreading, email

I have a simple function that sends out emails, how would I go about using threads to speed email delivery?

Sample code would be ideal.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 8):

Use SendAsync isntead.

Comment: You can still only send 1 async. email at a time per Smtp client (it won't let you call it if there's another still in progress). So this route isn't very helpful when sending large email batches from one client. And if you say then use multiple clients, then async really only speeds up the rate at you can create the clients and tell them to Send...

Better option: 
Creating threads, making a client for each one, and using regular Send(). At least in my testing, threading ends up being the much faster option, of course it also depends on hardware.

Comment: Le function is poop... "After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send or SendAsync."

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following link for a demonstration of the sendAsync method. [MSDN]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/x5x13z6h(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Le function is poop... "After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send or SendAsync."

Answer (score 2):

You can run the function in another thread. Being SendMail your mail sender function you can:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { SendMail(message); });
```

Answer (score 2):

IN 4.0 you can use the following,

```
new Thread(x => SendMail(message)).Start();
```

and

```
public static void SendEmail(MailMessage message)
{
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.XXXXXX.com"))
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your class with a static void method that will make your class start doing what you want to do on the separate thread with something like:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Thread newThread =  new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork));
        newThread.Start();
    }
}

class Work 
{
    Work() {}
    public static void DoWork() {}
}
```

Another alternative is to use the ThreadPool class if you dont want to manage your threads yourself.

More info on Threads - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx

More info on ThreadPool - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Having a seperate thread will not speed the delivery of email however. All it will do is return control back to the calling method faster. So unless you need to do that, i wouldnt even bother with it.

Comment: If you are sending multiple e-mails you don't want to leave the user waiting for ages.

Answer (score 1):

When you send e-mails using multiple threads, be careful about getting identified as spam by your isp. It will be better to opt for a smaller batches with some delay between each batch.

Answer (score -1):

You know what would be nicer and easier is to create an application back end and send emails every 30 minutes.  Throw the information into a database that you need to send to and from there, create an application pool that launches every 30 minutes.  When it launches, you can send an email.  No need to wait for your event handler to send the email...

It works for us.  Just thought it would help for you.