# Send Yahoo mail through C# Winforms using SMTP

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

I'm using the code below to send an e-mail through Gmail server. What I want to know is what do I have to change/remove from the code below to be able to send an e-mail from Yahoo mail server using my C# WinForm application.

And also, if you know how to make it's performance faster, please let me know. It takes like 20 to 22 seconds to send an e-mail using this code. Thank you.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sendermail@gmail.com", "Sender name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("recipientmail@gmail.com", "Recipient name");
const string fromPassword = "mypassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
string body = "E-mail content";

var smtp = new SmtpClient();
{
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
}

using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
{
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = body;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Use threading to send the message. It will still take time on the backend, but your application will stay repsonsive. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133287/threading-when-sending-emails

Answer (score 1):

Everything in this bit would need to change to reflect Yahoo's SMTP server:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
{
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
}
```

you'll need to change these to reflect the [settings here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-33.html).

With regards to time I doubt any reputable open SMTP will provide any 'fast' service in an attempt to prevent being used for spam.

Comment: I've googled it and it says that I should replace that line with 'plus.mail.yahoo.com', but still it didn't worked. I think the SMTP port has to be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is too easy, but [Yahoo has a documentation on which ports and servers to use](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-33.html).

An excerpt:

```
Outgoing mail (SMTP) server: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com
                             Use SSL, port: 465, and use authentication

Account name/user name:      Your Business Email address
                             (such as you@widgetdesigns.com)

Email address:               Your Business Email address
                             (such as you@widgetdesigns.com)

Password:                    Your Business Email password
```